# "Failed to download repository information"

Tags: steam

I can't update for some reasons.. This is what I get each time:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/i18n/Translation-en  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 23.15.8.226 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: enter this in terminal sudo apt-get update then try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Software Center and open the "**Edit** -> **Software Sources...**" menu:

[image]

Deselect all the lines containing `steampowered.com` and your next update should run just fine.

Note: their servers may be busy or down. you could try to re-enable them later.

Comment: Could you explain the downvote(s) please

Comment: Please accept the answer thanks (See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Done.. Sorry it's my first time asking a question.. I tried to vote up the answer but couldn't due to being new. I must've voted down by mistake!